# How to handle sub-operations and keep functional with Ramda?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

How can I solve sub-operations in a single processing pipe, using ramda? Say I have an array of numbers, and want to return an array of the percentage each number is equivalent in the total:

```
const values = [1, 5, 8, 2, 5]

// 1 - Get total: 1 + 5 + 8 + 2 + 5 = 21
// 2 - Return percentages of each item:
//
// 2.1 - 1: (1 * 100) / 21 = 4.761904762%
// 2.2 - 5: (5 * 100) / 21 = 23.80952381%
// 2.3 - 8: (5 * 100) / 21 = 38.095238095%
// 2.4 - 2: (5 * 100) / 21 = 9.523809524
// 2.5 - 5: (5 * 100) / 21 = 23.80952381%
percents(values) // [4.76, 23,80, 9.52, 23,80]
```

Can I solve this using a single Ramda pipe/composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could do this:

```js
const {compose, map, multiply, chain, flip, divide, sum} = R

const percentages = chain(tot => values => map(val =>  100 * val / tot, values), sum)
console.log(percentages([1, 5, 8, 2, 5]))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

This could also be written slightly more compactly as

```
const percentages = chain(compose(map, tot => val => 100 * val / tot), sum)
```

And if you're trying to go point-free, I suppose this would do as well:

```
const percentages = compose(map(multiply(100)), chain(compose(map, flip(divide)), sum))
```

although I find it less readable.

#### Note

This is a single pipeline *as code*, but `chain` applied to functions works something like `chain(f, g)(x) //~> f(g(x), x)`.  (Technically, that's not true, it's more like `chain(f, g)(x) //~> f(g(x))(x)`, but often with Ramda, they're similar.)  So there will be two separate iterations of your values, once to compute the total, and once to calculate each percentage given the value and the total.  This is essential, of course, mathematically.  You can't calculate the sum and use that sum simultaneously, but I didn't want the notion of a single pipeline to get confused here.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, for catching that typo!